# Problem with routing when I put some route parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I define a route parameter in my browser URL, the route that is connected with that URL sends me errors with the routing of the public folder (that contains my CSS, JS, etc.).

The structure of the app is like this:

```
app
|
|-- public
|      └-- css
|           └-- profile.css
|
|-- views
|     └-- profile.html
|
|-- server.js
```

In my server.js I have this:

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'))

app.get('/profile/:userId', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/profile.html'))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

On my `profile.html` I have linked the CSS file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/profile.css">
```

And when I go to the URL `http://localhost:3000/profile/someId` the HTML runs correctly but I have some errors with my static folders like this:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/profile/css/profile.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

When I delete the `:userId` parameter from the `server.js` file, the CSS runs perfectly, like this:

```
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/profile.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a path relative to the current directory `./css/profile.css` instead of one relative to the site's root.

TL;DR: just change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/profile.css">` to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css">
```

Now here's a more complete answer:

`./css/profile.css` means "starting at the current directory, go to the `css` folder, and get the file `profile.css`". The current directory for `http://localhost:3000/profile/someId` is `http://localhost:3000/profile`, so the browser will try to get `http://localhost:3000/profile/css/profile.css`. Usually, this will just give you a "404 Not Found" error because the CSS file is not there (it is actually at `http://localhost:3000/css/profile.css`).

However, your code uses the parameter `:userId`, so when the browser asks the server for `http://localhost:3000/profile/css/profile.css`, the server thinks that `:userId` is `css/profile.css` and calls the GET handler for `/profile/:userId`. Your GET handler sends back some HTML, but the browser is expecting CSS, so the browser says that the file type (MIME type) is wrong.

At this point, the answer should be clear: all you need to do is get the correct path. `/css/profile.css` means "go to the root of this site (`http://localhost:3000`), go to the `css` folder, and get the file `profile.css`". This is what you actually want to be doing.

Comment: Perfect !!! So clear!!. One question more, when you said that i need to go to the root (localhost:3000), is actually the 'public' folder, because the app.use(express.static...) no??